# Windows samba share: drop cache after DNS change

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, server-message-block, cache

Suppose I have following entry in `hosts.cfg` file:

```
1.2.3.4 test # foo machine
```

I start script that every second call `ping test` and cat `\\test\share\machine-name.txt`

Script output: `IP: 1.2.3.4; machine name: foo`

Then I change `hosts.cfg` to following:

```
1.2.3.5 test # bar machine
```

Now script output is following: `IP: 1.2.3.5; machine name: foo`  # bar is expected!

Problem: `\\test\share\machine-name.txt` still points **to old location**

I've found only one solution how to resolve this problem: restart `LanmanWorkstation` service. But the problem with `LanmanWorkstation` service is that it takes too much time to restart and sometimes it completely hangs on stop operation.

**Question:** how to clear/reset Windows SMB cache? Something like `ipconfig /flushdns`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that they're being stored in the NetBios Resolver Cache?

To check try:

```
nbtstat -c
```

if that turns out to be the problem, the following will restart it.

```
nbtstat -R
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not NetBios Resolver Cache issue